# How to solve $\left(\frac3{p-3}-1\right)\left(2+\frac4{p-2}\right)=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm currently preparing myself for uni and thus learning on my own. This equation is killing me as the book doesn't explain how to solve it.

$$\left(\frac3{p-3}-1\right)\left(2+\frac4{p-2}\right)=0$$

Comment: When the product of two numbers is 0, at least one of them has to be 0. Does this help?

Comment: In future, [please use MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Any advanced users that want to close this has no sympathy.  The motivation is stated.   It says they are stuck.   Instead of voting it down, they can leave off or help them.

Comment: Try multiplying both side of the equation by $(p-3)(p-2)$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 5):

By Null -Factor law,
If xy = 0 ,
Then, either x = 0 or y = 0.

Hence, applying this property in this given equation :
We get ,

Equate both terms on Left side factor  and Right side factor of left hand side equation  to $0$
$$p-3 = \frac 31  \implies  p = 6$$
Or :
$$p-2= -2 \implies  p = 0$$ 
So, either $p = 0$ or $p = 6$

Comment: [Please use MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @Doraemon Welcome to MSE. Great that you are giving answers. As John Doe said pleas invest some time in the use of MathJaX. It is what we use to format our maths on this site. 

Some friendly advice: If I had to guess, in a case like this the OP would be helped greatly if you say **why** he shoud equate $\frac{3}{p-3}-1$ to $0$. And mind that LHS means "left hand side of an equation". I assume you ment to say the left factor.

Comment: Thanks Sir, Gebruiker : I means "LHS" as left factor only.      But, there is still one doubt that I am new here and dont know , how to get my answers of my questions. I am struggling to get answer to my problems here. It is not getting answered till so much time.

Answer (score 2):

By the null factor law, if $xy=0$ then $x=0$ or $y=0$. Apply this to your equation and you'll get two answers.